# Intellij - Missing basic intention actions

Tags: intellij-idea

I have absolutely no idea why IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 (Community Edition), just after creating a new Java class and typing in some random fields, doesn't show basic intention actions like generate constructor, getter, setter etc.
I know it looks so trivial - despite I'm Java beginner and IntelliJ IDEA's newbie this thing occurs for first time:

```
 class Product {
    String product;
    double price;
}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the wrong shortcut (**Show Intention Actions** or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of **Generate** or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>).

See [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/generate-getters-and-setters/).